# Can "mode" be used as "mean" and "median" are?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, technical

It'd be normal to hear sentences like these:

> The mean ticket price for the concert was $56.50.
>
> The median ticket price for the concert was $61.

But what about:

> The mode ticket price for the concert was $40.

Is this an acceptable way to use the word "mode?" I would typically expect to hear, "The mode of ticket prices for the concert was $40," but the former arrangement is nice because it's more concise.

Comment: "The most common ticket price for the concert was $40."

Comment: The average ticket price was...,  mean, mode and median are statistical terms!

Comment: @PeterShor Viable in casual contexts, but lacks the sense of statistical precision I'd like to convey.

Comment: @Josh61: when you say *"the average ticket price"*, nobody will understand you to mean *"the mode"*.

Comment: The most common ticket price is not the the mean or the median .. I think OP needs to rephrase the question.

Comment: @Josh61: I'm confused. The question doesn't even come close to *implying* that the most common ticket price is the mean or median. The question hasn't been edited, so you're not responding to a prior version. What's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question can be restated as "Can *mode* be used as an adjective?" for which one just needs to look in a dictionary.

OED lists *mode* as a noun and a verb, but not an adjective.

However, there is an adjective *modal,* for which OED gives

> **6. a.** *Statistics.* Of, relating to, or of the nature of a mode; (of a value, etc.) that occurs most frequently in a particular sample or population. Cf. **mode** *n.* 13.

and there is a citation which exactly mirrors your example, although it appears the BBC thought it necessary to explain the word:

> 1968   *Listener* 25 July 101/1   The administrators we saw..had averaged only 2·8 years in all their completed jobs in the class; in fact, the modal (most frequently occurring) period in completed jobs was two years.

Comment: Nicely reduced and resolved. Accepted for explaining the crux of the issue: “mode” is not an adjective.

Answer (score 9):

Neither *mean*, *median*, nor *mode* are likely to occur in casual conversation or writing. They are statistical terms, and would really only be used in a technical context. What you'd actually find in "regular" writing would be statements such as:

> The **average** ticket price was $56.50.

(In nontechnical usage, *mean* has too many other, well, *mean*ings, so "average" is used instead.)

> The **middle of the range of** ticket prices was $61.

(This one is debatable: people do use *median* in nontechnical contexts, but you can never tell whether they're using it correctly, or whether they're using it as a synonym of *average*.)

> The **most common** ticket price was $40.

(While it's true that *mode* has the adjectival form *modal*, almost nobody would know what you mean by "modal ticket price". Heck, I have a degree in math, and if I encountered that in a magazine or blog, **I** wouldn't know what it meant. In those rare cases when you need to talk about the mode, you're much better off describing the meaning in nontechnical terms, such as the "most common" phrasing I used above, or if you want to be slightly more accurate, something like "most frequently occurring".)

Comment: I'd already upvoted @Andrew's answer, but this is *much* better. As someone who *doesn't* have a degree in maths, I'm not too bothered about the difference between *mean, median, modal* values. In practice I'd probably just understand them all as *"Pseud's word for **average**"* anyway.

Comment: @FF I'll annoy you with 'midmark' then.

Comment: I am a statistician. This is the correct answer, in every way. Mean, median and mode are used to describe probability and/ or frequency distributions. It would be absurd to use the terms conversationally, for a general audience,

Comment: If someone was using mean, mode, modal or median in a casual conversation I would probably be asking from which institution had he escaped.

Comment: Great usage notes. To me, invoking "mode" implies you've crunched the numbers, whereas "most common" is looser and hence less informative ("we most commonly play in bars"). "Most common" can also unintentionally convey "majority" ("bands most commonly arrive by bus"). Your general point — find another way to phrase the concept — seems wise. I for one wish "mode" were part of our vernacular, since it's unambiguous, distinct, and useful.

Comment: @duozmo: as I noted, if you want to be (slightly) more accurate, you can say "most frequently occurring". Beyond that, you can go the route of the OED quote that Andrew cites: use "modal (most frequently occurring)", i.e. use the technical term, but immediately define it.